# Excel place : between 4 numbers in text cell

Tags: excel, vba

First off i'm not here for a total solution but a point in the right direction.
Here's my problem
I have a worksheet with a named range of cells which contain text string such as

'Saturday 2200-0700 Sunday'
the text in these cells can vary depending on the day and times etc

What i'd like is to put a code together the place an : between the 4 numbers sections to turn them into a time format. That way down the line i can calculate shift hours etc.

so that i'd get this
'Saturday 22:00-07:00 Sunday'

Not sure where to start though.

Comment: do a substitute of "-" for ":"

Comment: @ solar mike not what i was after but thats my fault for vagueness, i've updated the question

Comment: Then use mid() or find() or both to get the 4 numbers after the first space and split adding the ":" - the & can help here. Repeat for the 4 numbers before the second space.

Comment: Giving one example is a bit limiting but.. could you subsitute `00` with `:00` ?

Comment: @CLR what happens if 00 is 15 or 17 or 35? as in any number between 00 and 59...

Comment: @SolarMike Hence my comment about the limitation of only providing one example.

Comment: @CLR which is why I wrote my answer the way I did as I had already caused an update to the question with my first comment.

Comment: @SolarMike, I like your answer. My comment wasn't a response to that, but to the question itself.

Comment: As I understand the OP, he wants 2 time formatted cells: one with 22:00 and one with 07:00 so he can calculate with it. So he does not want strings but real numeric datetimes.

Comment: Was simple with MS365 formulas: `=TEXTJOIN({" ","-"," "},,HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(A2," "),TOROW(TEXT(TEXTSPLIT(A2,"-"," ")+0,"00\:00"),3),TEXTAFTER(A2," ",2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)-3)&":"&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)+3),5)&":"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)-2)
```

And a small amendment to this formula to remove the days:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)-3),2)&":"&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)+3),5)&":"&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)-2),2)
```

Comment: Looks so similar to what I produced above.

Answer (score 3):

So like this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1))&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1,2)&":"&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+3,5)&":"&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+3,20)
```

[image]

Of course getting Excel to recognize the time will need to split out the 22:00 etc.

Based on the comment:
So to just get the time:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1,2)&":"&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+3,5)&":"&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+3,3)
```

As for not ending up with "::" then do an if() to check for ":" first:

```
=if(iferror(find(":",a1,1),0)>=1,A1,"do function")
```

So if ":" is there it just repeats A1 if not you apply the function.

Comment: I'm thinking that I could apply something like that further down my process pipeline. Eventually I get to a point where i've removed all special character (besides '-') text and spaces. which would leave me with 2200-0700. Can your solution be adapted to work with this example? also I need to make sure it doesnt insert : if they are already there. I dont want to get 22::00-07::00 if you get my drift

Comment: @MJobbson well, you said you weren't here for a total solution but your comment here seems to need one. I have shown how to get to the final point but you can do the last step.

Comment: thanks for your help, you've given me more guidance than I expected. Combining your suggestions i've got (my data is in E1983) =IF(IFERROR(FIND(":",E1983,1),0)>=1,E1983)&MID(E1983,FIND(" ",E1983,1)+1,2)&":"&MID(E1983,FIND(" ",E1983,1)+3,5)&":"&MID(E1983,FIND("-",E1983,1)+3,3) However this is giving me a value error so I've gone wrong somewhere. thank you for the help though. Very much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Another way......  bit long winded though.

```
=LET(Original, $B$2,
           SplitBySpace, TEXTSPLIT(Original, " "),
           HourPart,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(SplitBySpace,2),"-"),
           Converted, LEFT(HourPart,2) & ":" & RIGHT(HourPart,2),
           RejoinConverted, TEXTJOIN("-",FALSE,Converted),
           Return, TEXTJOIN(" ",FALSE,INDEX(SplitBySpace,,1),RejoinConverted,INDEX(SplitBySpace,,3)),
           Return)
```

**Edit:** Have updated the Return argument to use `TEXTJOIN`.  Didn't work first time, but must've been a typo.

[image]

Comment: Now that is different to mine :) plus 1.

Comment: @SolarMike Cheers.  I try my best. :)  Was going to say I'm not sure why I couldn't use `TEXTJOIN` on the Return argument though - tested again, and it worked this time so going to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but if you were after a total solution, you could use the following UDF on a cell containing that text:

```
Function hour_difference(DayTime As String)

    'declarations
    Dim wk As String, seg As Variant, StartDayOfWeek As Integer, EndDayOfWeek As Integer, StartTimeofDay As String, EndTimeofDay As String
    Dim StartDateTime As Double, EndDateTime As Double
    
    'enumerate weekdays
    wk = "SuMoTuWeThFrSa"
    seg = Split(DayTime, " ")
    StartDayOfWeek = (InStr(1, wk, Left(seg(0), 2), vbTextCompare) + 1) / 2
    EndDayOfWeek = (InStr(1, wk, Left(seg(2), 2), vbTextCompare) + 1) / 2
    
    'get times
    StartTimeofDay = Split(seg(1), "-")(0)
    EndTimeofDay = Split(seg(1), "-")(1)
    
    'calculate difference
    StartDateTime = StartDayOfWeek * 24 + Left(StartTimeofDay, 2) + Right(StartTimeofDay, 2) / 60
    EndDateTime = EndDayOfWeek * 24 + Left(EndTimeofDay, 2) + Right(EndTimeofDay, 2) / 60
    hour_difference = (EndDateTime + 168 - StartDateTime) Mod 168

End Function
```

Input: "Saturday 2200-0700 Sunday"

Output: 9